# SharedPreferences not returning last open/close time in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to check if the app is opened in the last hour. I'm using the `SharedPreferences` class to do this. However, although I only run the app within a couple of minutes, when I check my current time and last run time, the time difference is like 5 hours.

And I'm doing this on `Android Studio`. I'm not sure if closing the emulator and run the app again to open the emulator would affect this.

I tried running in debug mode but it has never hit something less than an hour.

```
public class MainWindowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public boolean runLastHour = false;

    SharedPreferences pref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_window);

        pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_window, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        long lastRun = pref.getLong("LAST_RUN", -1);
        if (lastRun == -1){
            //first run after install
        } else {
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (currentTime - lastRun <= (1000 * 60 * 60)) {// less than 1 hour
                runLastHour = true;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        pref.edit().putLong("LAST_RUN", System.currentTimeMillis()).apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: put `pref.edit().putLong` to `onPause` instead of `onStop`

Comment: apply() == commit() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling super class's onStop method first and then trying to commit your value in SharedPreference. Instead you should first commit the value & then call super class's onStop() method.

Try this way,

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    pref.edit().putLong("LAST_RUN", System.currentTimeMillis()).apply();
    super.onStop();
}
```

call commit() or apply() method before calling the super class's method.